# Game engine for 2D games in Java

Tags: java, performance, object-oriented

I am writing a 2D game engine library that I can use for simple future games, and I've been told that it is written very procedural rather than objected oriented. I was wondering what I should do to fix this, or how other game engines are usually written. My engine is very laggy, and I think this is why. Here is the main body of the engine, and [this is my GitHub account](https://github.com/quiteaniceguy) if you want to look at the rest.

```
package Platformer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent.Type;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public abstract class GameComponent extends JPanel{
    //delete this i think
    public static int ticks=0;
    public Rectangle box;

    private final int FPS=40;
    public int xMovement=0;
    public int yMovement=0;
    public final int A=0,D=1,S=2,W=3,SPACE=4;
    public boolean[] keyPressed=new boolean[5];
    private InputController keyListener;
    public ArrayList<Entity> Entities=new ArrayList<Entity>();
    HashMap sounds=new HashMap();

    public boolean drawLines=false;
    public int xAxisLines=40;
    public int yAxisLines=27;

    Quadtree quad=new Quadtree(0,new Rectangle(0,0,1920,1080));


    public GameComponent(){
        keyListener=new InputController();
        box=new Rectangle(90,90,20,20);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow(true);
        run();

    }
    public void run(){
        addKeyListener(keyListener);

        Timer timer=new Timer(1000/FPS, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //movement();

                gameLoop();
                collisions();
                repaint();
                ticks++;
                if(ticks==360 || ticks==1000){
                    try{
                        playSound("spun");



                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g.create();
        //g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        //g2d.fill(box);




        for(Entity entity: Entities){
            g2d.drawImage(entity.IMAGE, entity.getX(),entity.getY(), entity.IMAGE.getWidth(), entity.IMAGE.getHeight(), null);
            g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(entity.NAME), entity.getX(), entity.getY());
        }
        ///draw lines in window if enabiled
        if(drawLines){
            drawLines(g2d);
        }
        ///do collisions

        g2d.dispose();

    }

    class InputController implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyPressed[W]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyPressed[S]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                keyPressed[A]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                keyPressed[D]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                keyPressed[SPACE]=true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyPressed[W]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyPressed[S]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                keyPressed[A]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                keyPressed[D]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                keyPressed[SPACE]=false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public abstract void gameLoop();
    public void drawLines(Graphics2D g2d){
        for(int i=0;i<1920;i+=1920/xAxisLines){
            g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, 1080);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1080;i+=1080/yAxisLines){
            g2d.drawLine(0, i, 1920, i);
        }
    }
    public void collisions(){
    ////collisions!

        ArrayList<Entity> returnEntities=new ArrayList<Entity>();
        quad.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<Entities.size();i++){
            quad.insert(Entities.get(i));
        }

        for(int i=0;i <Entities.size();i++){
            returnEntities.clear();
            returnEntities=quad.retrieve(returnEntities,Entities.get(i));

            for(Entity e:returnEntities){
                //System.out.println(Entities.get(i).NAME+" could collide with "+e.NAME);
                if(Math.abs(Entities.get(i).getX()-e.getX())<= Entities.get(i).IMAGE.getWidth()/2+e.IMAGE.getWidth()/2 && Math.abs(Entities.get(i).getY()-e.getY())<= Entities.get(i).IMAGE.getHeight()/2+e.IMAGE.getHeight()/2 && Entities.get(i)!=e){
                    //System.out.println(Entities.get(i).NAME+" is colliding with "+e.NAME);
                }
            }
        }
            ////collisions!
        /*
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(quad.getIndex(Entities.get(0))));
        System.out.println(Entities.get(0).bounds.x);
        System.out.println(Entities.get(0).bounds.y);
        */
    }
    public void playSound(String fileName) throws IOException, 
      UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
        File clipFile=new File("assets//"+fileName+".wav");

        class AudioListener implements LineListener {
            private boolean done = false;
            @Override public synchronized void update(LineEvent event) {
              Type eventType = event.getType();
              if (eventType == Type.STOP || eventType == Type.CLOSE) {
                done = true;
                notifyAll();
              }
            }
            public synchronized void waitUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
              while (!done) {}
            }
        }
        class SoundThread implements Runnable  {
            AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
            public SoundThread() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
              audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipFile);
            }

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try{
                  Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
                  clip.addLineListener(listener);
                  clip.open(audioInputStream);
                  try{
                      clip.start();
                      listener.waitUntilDone();
                  }
                  finally{
                      clip.close();
                  }
              }
              catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally{
                  try {
                      audioInputStream.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }

        }
        Thread thread=new Thread(new SoundThread());
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Normally, game engines for Java Swing are not written using Swing components like JPanel.  Also, you should use key bindings, rather than key listeners.

Comment: What are they written with instead of Swing?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void playSound(String fileName) throws IOException, 
  UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
    File clipFile=new File("assets//"+fileName+".wav");

    class AudioListener implements LineListener {
        private boolean done = false;
        @Override public synchronized void update(LineEvent event) {
          Type eventType = event.getType();
          if (eventType == Type.STOP || eventType == Type.CLOSE) {
            done = true;
            notifyAll();
          }
        }
        public synchronized void waitUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
          while (!done) {}
        }
    }
    class SoundThread implements Runnable  {
        AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
        public SoundThread() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
          audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipFile);
        }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          try{
              Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
              clip.addLineListener(listener);
              clip.open(audioInputStream);
              try{
                  clip.start();
                  listener.waitUntilDone();
              }
              finally{
                  clip.close();
              }
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally{
              try {
                  audioInputStream.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }

    }
    Thread thread=new Thread(new SoundThread());
    thread.start();
}
```

This method is one good way to burn a lot of CPU cycles.

You do not need a separate thread for this. If you simply moved the file opening and closing to the `AudioListener`, you could handle the file closing in the `update` function. This saves you a lot of spin looping and ought to give you a boost in performance.